# Property 'getNetworkId' does not exist on type 'never' Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm currently working with the cardano serialization library to code crypto transactions in typescript. I'm referencing a wallet connector template that has example code for transactions but is all written in Javascript. So in translating it over I've received a number of syntax errors that have generally been easy to resolve until now. I have a number of ts(2532) errors (Object is possibly 'undefined' that are solved through '?' chaining, I know that's not my best solution but for now I'm trying to get it error free first. When I utilize a ? operator chain though I then get the property does not exist on type 'never' error in the following code

```
  getNetworkId = async () => {
  try {
    const networkId = await this?.API?.getNetworkId()
    this.setState({ networkId })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } }
```

Below I've included the majority of the code down until that error

```
    export default class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
    API: undefined
    protocolParams: {
    linearFee: { minFeeA: string; minFeeB: string }
    minUtxo: string
    poolDeposit: string
    keyDeposit: string
    maxValSize: number
    maxTxSize: number
    priceMem: number
    priceStep: number
    coinsPerUtxoWord: string
  }
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectedTabId: '1',
      whichWalletSelected: undefined,
      walletFound: false,
      walletIsEnabled: false,
      walletName: undefined,
      walletIcon: undefined,
      walletAPIVersion: undefined,
      wallets: [],

      networkId: undefined,
      Utxos: undefined,
      CollatUtxos: undefined,
      balance: undefined,
      changeAddress: undefined,
      rewardAddress: undefined,
      usedAddress: undefined,

      txBody: undefined,
      txBodyCborHex_unsigned: '',
      txBodyCborHex_signed: '',
      submittedTxHash: '',

      addressBech32SendADA:
        'addr_test1qrt7j04dtk4hfjq036r2nfewt59q8zpa69ax88utyr6es2ar72l7vd6evxct69wcje5cs25ze4qeshejy828h30zkydsu4yrmm',
      lovelaceToSend: 3000000,
      assetNameHex: '4c494645',
      assetPolicyIdHex:
        'ae02017105527c6c0c9840397a39cc5ca39fabe5b9998ba70fda5f2f',
      assetAmountToSend: 5,
      addressScriptBech32:
        'addr_test1wpnlxv2xv9a9ucvnvzqakwepzl9ltx7jzgm53av2e9ncv4sysemm8',
      datumStr: '12345678',
      plutusScriptCborHex: '4e4d01000033222220051200120011',
      transactionIdLocked: '',
      transactionIndxLocked: 0,
      lovelaceLocked: 3000000,
      manualFee: 900000,
    }

    /**
     * When the wallet is connect it returns the connector which is
     * written to this API variable and all the other operations
     * run using this API object
     */
    this.API = undefined

    /**
     * Protocol parameters
     * @type {{
     * keyDeposit: string,
     * coinsPerUtxoWord: string,
     * minUtxo: string,
     * poolDeposit: string,
     * maxTxSize: number,
     * priceMem: number,
     * maxValSize: number,
     * linearFee: {minFeeB: string, minFeeA: string}, priceStep: number
     * }}
     */
    this.protocolParams = {
      linearFee: {
        minFeeA: '44',
        minFeeB: '155381',
      },
      minUtxo: '34482',
      poolDeposit: '500000000',
      keyDeposit: '2000000',
      maxValSize: 5000,
      maxTxSize: 16384,
      priceMem: 0.0577,
      priceStep: 0.0000721,
      coinsPerUtxoWord: '34482',
    }

    this.pollWallets = this.pollWallets.bind(this)
  }

  /**
   * Poll the wallets it can read from the browser.
   * Sometimes the html document loads before the browser initialized browser plugins (like Nami or Flint).
   * So we try to poll the wallets 3 times (with 1 second in between each try).
   *
   * Note: CCVault and Eternl are the same wallet, Eternl is a rebrand of CCVault
   * So both of these wallets as the Eternl injects itself twice to maintain
   * backward compatibility
   *
   * @param count The current try count.
   */
  pollWallets = (count = 0) => {
    const wallets = []
    for (const key in window.cardano) {
      if (window.cardano[key].enable && wallets.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        wallets.push(key)
      }
    }
    if (wallets.length === 0 && count < 3) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.pollWallets(count + 1)
      }, 1000)
      return
    }
    this.setState(
      {
        wallets,
        whichWalletSelected: wallets[0],
      },
      () => {
        this.refreshData()
      }
    )
  }

  /**
   * Handles the tab selection on the user form
   * @param tabId
   */
  handleTabId = (tabId: any) => this.setState({ selectedTabId: tabId })

  /**
   * Handles the radio buttons on the form that
   * let the user choose which wallet to work with
   * @param obj
   */
  handleWalletSelect = (obj: { target: { value: any } }) => {
    const whichWalletSelected = obj.target.value
    this.setState({ whichWalletSelected }, () => {
      this.refreshData()
    })
  }

  /**
   * Generate address from the plutus contract cborhex
   */
  generateScriptAddress = () => {
    // cborhex of the alwayssucceeds.plutus
    // const cborhex = "4e4d01000033222220051200120011";
    // const cbor = Buffer.from(cborhex, "hex");
    // const blake2bhash = blake.blake2b(cbor, 0, 28);

    const script = PlutusScript.from_bytes(
      Buffer.from(this.state.plutusScriptCborHex, 'hex')
    )
    // const blake2bhash = blake.blake2b(script.to_bytes(), 0, 28);
    const blake2bhash =
      '67f33146617a5e61936081db3b2117cbf59bd2123748f58ac9678656'
    const scripthash = ScriptHash.from_bytes(Buffer.from(blake2bhash, 'hex'))

    const cred = StakeCredential.from_scripthash(scripthash)
    const networkId = NetworkInfo.testnet().network_id()
    const baseAddr = EnterpriseAddress.new(networkId, cred)
    const addr = baseAddr.to_address()
    const addrBech32 = addr.to_bech32()

    // hash of the address generated from script
    console.log(Buffer.from(addr.to_bytes(), 'utf8').toString('hex'))

    // hash of the address generated using cardano-cli
    const ScriptAddress = Address.from_bech32(
      'addr_test1wpnlxv2xv9a9ucvnvzqakwepzl9ltx7jzgm53av2e9ncv4sysemm8'
    )
    console.log(Buffer.from(ScriptAddress.to_bytes(), 'utf8').toString('hex'))

    console.log(ScriptAddress.to_bech32())
    console.log(addrBech32)
  }

  /**
   * Checks if the wallet is running in the browser
   * Does this for Nami, Eternl and Flint wallets
   * @returns {boolean}
   */

  checkIfWalletFound = () => {
    const walletKey = this.state.whichWalletSelected
    const walletFound = !!window?.cardano?.[walletKey]
    this.setState({ walletFound })
    return walletFound
  }

  /**
   * Checks if a connection has been established with
   * the wallet
   * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
   */
  checkIfWalletEnabled = async () => {
    let walletIsEnabled = false

    try {
      const walletName = this.state.whichWalletSelected
      walletIsEnabled = await window.cardano[walletName].isEnabled()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    this.setState({ walletIsEnabled })

    return walletIsEnabled
  }

  /**
   * Enables the wallet that was chosen by the user
   * When this executes the user should get a window pop-up
   * from the wallet asking to approve the connection
   * of this app to the wallet
   * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
   */

  enableWallet = async () => {
    const walletKey = this.state.whichWalletSelected
    try {
      this.API = await window.cardano[walletKey].enable()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    return this.checkIfWalletEnabled()
  }

  /**
   * Get the API version used by the wallets
   * writes the value to state
   * @returns {*}
   */
  getAPIVersion = () => {
    const walletKey = this.state.whichWalletSelected
    const walletAPIVersion = window?.cardano?.[walletKey].apiVersion
    this.setState({ walletAPIVersion })
    return walletAPIVersion
  }

  /**
   * Get the name of the wallet (nami, eternl, flint)
   * and store the name in the state
   * @returns {*}
   */

  getWalletName = () => {
    const walletKey = this.state.whichWalletSelected
    const walletName = window?.cardano?.[walletKey].name
    this.setState({ walletName })
    return walletName
  }

  /**
   * Gets the Network ID to which the wallet is connected
   * 0 = testnet
   * 1 = mainnet
   * Then writes either 0 or 1 to state
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   */
  getNetworkId = async () => {
      try {
        const networkId = await this?.API?.getNetworkId()
        this.setState({ networkId })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
  }

  /**
   * Gets the UTXOs from the user's wallet and then
   * stores in an object in the state
   * @returns {Promise<void>}
   */

  getUtxos = async () => {
    let Utxos = []

    try {
      const rawUtxos = await this?.API?.getUtxos()

      for (const rawUtxo of rawUtxos) {
        const utxo = TransactionUnspentOutput.from_bytes(
          Buffer.from(rawUtxo, 'hex')
        )
        const input = utxo.input()
        const txid = Buffer.from(
          input.transaction_id().to_bytes(),
          'utf8'
        ).toString('hex')
        const txindx = input.index()
        const output = utxo.output()
        const amount = output.amount().coin().to_str() // ADA amount in lovelace
        const multiasset = output.amount().multiasset()
        let multiAssetStr = ''

        if (multiasset) {
          const keys = multiasset.keys() // policy Ids of thee multiasset
          const N = keys.len()
          // console.log(`${N} Multiassets in the UTXO`)

          for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            const policyId = keys.get(i)
            const policyIdHex = Buffer.from(
              policyId.to_bytes(),
              'utf8'
            ).toString('hex')
            // console.log(`policyId: ${policyIdHex}`)
            const assets = multiasset.get(policyId)
            const assetNames = assets.keys()
            const K = assetNames.len()
            // console.log(`${K} Assets in the Multiasset`)

            for (let j = 0; j < K; j++) {
              const assetName = assetNames.get(j)
              const assetNameString = Buffer.from(
                assetName.name(),
                'utf8'
              ).toString()
              const assetNameHex = Buffer.from(
                assetName.name(),
                'utf8'
              ).toString('hex')
              const multiassetAmt = multiasset.get_asset(policyId, assetName)
              multiAssetStr += `+ ${multiassetAmt.to_str()} + ${policyIdHex}.${assetNameHex} (${assetNameString})`
              // console.log(assetNameString)
              // console.log(`Asset Name: ${assetNameHex}`)
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: You should properly type `API`.

Comment: @juliomalves Sorry for the late response but could you elaborate? I get what you mean but I've played around with the typing of it above the constructor but haven't solved the error